kinit: Invalid integer value while getting initial credentials
I am trying to configure a keytab file to use with my service principal for Kerberos authentication between my Linux (RHEL9) server and my Microsoft Windows 2022 Server. The service principal is MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP. When I generate the keytab file on my AD host (controller) and then upload it to my RHEL host and attempt to generate a ticket.
kinit -V -t /etc/test.keytab MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP

I always gets:
Using keytab: /etc/test.keytab
kinit: Invalid integer value while getting initial credentials

Also tried:
kinit MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP
kinit: Invalid integer value while getting initial credentials

Here's the background of how I configured my environment. First, I set my SQL Server service to run with my domain user EvolvenDBUser@EVOLVEN.CORP. I then generated a service principle for my user:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> setSPN EvolvenDBUser
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=EvolvenDBUser,CN=Users,DC=evolven,DC=corp:
        MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp
        MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp:1433

Next, I then generated a keytab file on my AD host via this command:
ktpass -princ MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP -mapuser EvolvenDBUser@EVOLVEN.CORP -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -pass <password> -out test.keytab -SetPass

It returns this:
Targeting domain controller: EC2AMAZ-AEHRC46.evolven.corp
Using legacy password setting method
Successfully mapped MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp to EvolvenDBUser.
Key created.
Output keytab to evolven.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 99 MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 20 etype 0x12 (AES256-SHA1) keylength 32 (0x0a32866cd2364109a006b483cedd8f6eee418f87b2b460d6be75e6763b1b0aef)

When I examine they keytab file on my RHEL host:
klist -k /etc/test.keytab 
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/test.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  18 MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP

On my RHEL host, my krb5.conf isn't super fancy but I can confirm it supports the encryption settings I want to use.
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EVOLVEN.CORP
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    ticket_lifetime = 30d
    renew_lifetime = 30d
    forwardable = true
    udp_preference_limit = 1  # Forces TCP if UDP fails
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96

[realms]
    EVOLVEN.CORP = {
        kdc = EC2AMAZ-AEHRC46.evolven.corp
        admin_server = EC2AMAZ-AEHRC46.evolven.corp
    }

[domain_realm]
    .evolven.corp = EVOLVEN.CORP
    evolven.corp = EVOLVEN.CORP

I've tried many things:

I have enabled user supports AES-128 and AES-256 in AD.
Changed the password of the AD user and then regenerated the keytab file. I also removed special characters in the password thinking that it be might be causing an issue. Still the samne.
Did a kdestroy to remove all old tickets.
I saw a post here: kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials.
Not sure why, but I do not see any logs even though I've enabled logging.

I tried to do: ktutil:  add_entry -password -p MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP -k 18 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 -f
and I get back
add_entry: Invalid integer value while adding new entry

So something is clearly wrong here with my service principle authentication. What do I do to resolve so I can generate tickets?


Is RHEL the client and Win2022 the SQL server, or is it the other way around? 2) If RHEL is the client and Win2022 the server, then why is the RHEL client trying to authenticate as a service principal? 3) If Windows is the client and RHEL is the server, then why is RHEL trying to kinit like a client?



The RHEL server is the client running a tomcat app and it is trying to authenticate with the Windows Server SQL Server database via JDBC. 2) I am not sure frankly. Essentially, I want my Tomcat service which uses JDBC, to be able to communicate with the MSSQL server via integrated auth. My understanding is that you need to setup kerberos auth in order for this to work.


I also verified that the key version is the same in my keytab.

You have not used -k option in kinit.  -k signifies keytab file usage. Also DNS lookup is recommended.

Invalid integer is an error that occurs during krb5.conf parsing. Most likely this is because of your udp_preference_limit, which is set to 1  # Forces TCP if UDP fails – that's not a valid number, as krb5.conf does not support same-line comments.
That aside: You have two entities (client and service) but only one AD account between both, and this is not how you're supposed to use Kerberos.
As a general rule, clients for a service should never be using the same principal as the service – you should create a dedicated user account (without an SPN) for each client.
(When you do kinit MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-whatever, you aren't getting tickets for the MSSQL server – you're getting tickets as the MSSQL server, which is the opposite of what you're probably trying to do.)
Keep in mind that a keytab is literally the account's password in different form, so if you normally wouldn't tell clients the service account's password, then you shouldn't be giving clients a service keytab either. (Much like you also wouldn't give webapp users a copy of the server's HTTPS private key...)

OK so I get this straight: My Active Directory (AD) EvolvenDBUser is associated with my Service Principle (MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp@EVOLVEN.CORP) and is set to run the SQL Service. I created another AD  account called DBClientUser and create a new login within the SQL Server database set to Windows Authentication with this user. I need to create a JaaS config for the JDBC adapter to connect via integrated authentication. Is there a way NOT to use a keytab file since they are on the same domain?

The client needs to load user credentials from somewhere so that it could get tickets – the machine's "same domain" credentials are not enough for that. (Unless constrained delegation is used, but that's more work and more security risk for not much gain...) Normally Windows clients know the password (e.g. user logon password or service account password) and they can just use it to get the Kerberos ticket, but Linux services start without a password being specified anywhere, so they need to get the credentials from a keytab file instead. (A keytab is practically the same password, hashed.)

Thanks for that. Your syntax advice worked. The last piece is trying to get my JDBC adapter to connect to my database. I created the two users. The SPN user and the keytab for the client user. I can get a ticket with they key tab file. jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp:1433;DatabaseName=master;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true. I keep getting Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: AP_REP token id does not match!). My jaas config is using the client user and key tab. Any ideas?

None for JDBC specifically – if you can, try verifying the client keytab using kinit and maybe (for example) ldapsearch -Y GSS-SPNEGO -H ldap://your-dc.evolven.corp as another Kerberos-based service. Another issue that comes to mind is that traditionally Linux Kerberos treats principal names as case-sensitive (so lowercase server name may help), and that it uses rDNS to resolve the principal name (so rdns = false in your krb5.conf is recommended).

Hate to spam. It worth posting a new question with this aused by: "GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: AP_REP token id does not match!)" or just change this?

I'd say post a new thread, it's a bit too far from the original topic.

Thanks for the help! Eventually got it working! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78990809/defective-token-detected-mechanism-level-ap-rep-token-id-does-not-match-via?noredirect=1#comment139276249_78990809.
