Defective token detected (Mechanism level: AP_REP token id does not match!) via Integrated auth using JDBC
Trying to get database connectivity from a Tomcat application running on Linux (RHEL) to a Windows host running SQL Server via JDBC and integrated auth with Kerberos. Continually bumping into:
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:48e48e7d-9590-4d72-bde7-085fa6df61d8
    at 
    at <Ommitted>
    ... 8 more
Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: AP_REP token id does not match!)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.AcceptSecContextToken.<init>(AcceptSecContextToken.java:80)

Both of my Windows and Evolven Server on the same domain (EVOLVEN.CORP). I've configured two users:

evolvendbuser (This is for the Service Principle and runs the SQL service).
evolvendbclientuser (This user is for the "client" I.E Redhat and also has an integrated auth user in SQL server as a sysadmin).

The environment looks like this, I've configured a Service Principle with my MSSQL host with the evolvendbuser username with this command:
setspn -A MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp:1433 evolvendbuser

Confirmed I have SPNs in place for my user and MSSQL host.
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=evolvendbuser,CN=Users,DC=evolven,DC=corp:
        MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp
        MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp:1433

Next, I generated a keytab file for my client user evolvendbclientuser:
ktpass -princ evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP -mapuser EVOLVEN\evolvendbclientuser -crypto ALL -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -pass <password> -out evolvendbclientuser.keytab -SetPass

I then take this keyfile and added it to my RHEL Server host for use with my JDBC and Jaas config.
Keytab looks fine:
[root@evolvenserver opt]# klist -k /etc/evolvendbclientuser.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/evolvendbclientuser.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   5 evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP
   5 evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP
   5 evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP
   5 evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP
   5 evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP

I tested I can get a ticket with:
kinit -kt /etc/evolvendbclientuser.keytab evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP

Also did:
[root@evolvenserver opt]# kvno MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp:1433
 MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp:1433@EVOLVEN.CORP: kvno = 20

My JaaS config for the JDBC adapter:
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="/etc/evolvendbclientuser.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    principal="evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP"
    doNotPrompt=true
    debug=true;
};

My krb5.conf file is pretty basic:
[libdefaults]
    rnds = false
    default_realm = EVOLVEN.CORP
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    ticket_lifetime = 30d
    renew_lifetime = 30d
    forwardable = true
    udp_preference_limit = 0
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
    permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac

[realms]
    EVOLVEN.CORP = {
        kdc = EC2AMAZ-AEHRC46.evolven.corp
        admin_server = EC2AMAZ-AEHRC46.evolven.corp
    }

[domain_realm]
    .evolven.corp = EVOLVEN.CORP
    evolven.corp = EVOLVEN.CORP

When I try to connect to the MSSQL instance using integrated auth via JDBC:
java -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false \
     -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/tomcat/bin/jaas.conf \
     -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf \
     -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true \
     -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true \
     -jar ms-sqlserver-jdbc-1.0.jar \
     "jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp:1433;DatabaseName=master;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true"

I always get:
<A bunch of hexdecimal gunk/binary stream>            
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_IN_PROCESS
15:00:29.503 [main] INFO Main - Time elapsed: 28941
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:a6a73dc6-2b15-46d8-b014-183f8c99c8e2
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3208)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthHandShake(KerbAuthentication.java:178)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.generateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:209)
    Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: AP_REP token id does not match!)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.AcceptSecContextToken.<init>(AcceptSecContextToken.java:80)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:755)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthHandShake(KerbAuthentication.java:158)
        ... 26 more


The network is wide open for all traffic. I can ping the MSSQL server from my RHEL host with no issues on all protocols.
I did a nslookup on all the servers everything resolves to EVOLVEN.CORP.
I lowercased the SPN to be on the safe side but have also tried with uppercase SPNs (I.E. MSSQLSvc/MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp:1433). Still nothing.
Both AES-128 and AES-256 encryption are enabled on the users within AD. I've trid keytabs with different encryption settings. Still nothing.
Tried various settings with udp_preference_limit = 0. I've set a high level (1800 and 0 to disable UDP). Still no joy.
My MSSQL server accepts TCP traffic and I can connect to from my RHEL server with sqlcmd.

How else do I debug? Completely stuck.

verify that kerberos is working for non-java connections:  'select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid'  should return 'KERBEROS'

Also, which version of the JDBC mssql driver are you using and what is the version of sql server you are connecting to?

I logged into the database with SQL auth and ran the query select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid' should return 'KERBEROS'. I got nothing back. I'm using jdbc mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar and SQL Server 20.2.30 on Windows Server 2022.

I hope this helps anyone stuck but clearly there was something wrong with my configurations. I started from scratch and started by creating two new users in Active Directory:

evolvendbuser (Service Principle User)
evolvendbclientuser (The client based user on my tomcat server).

Set the evolvendbuser to run my SQL Server Service. Then, created an SQL "Windows Authentication" based login within the SQL Server database for the domain evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP user.
Then I created the SPN for my evolvendbuser on the Windows AD domain host:
setspn -A MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp:1433 evolvendbuser 
setspn -A MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp evolvendbuser

Verified they were in place:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> setspn -L evolvendbuser
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=evolvendbuser,CN=Users,DC=evolven,DC=corp:
        MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp:1433
        MSSQLSvc/mssql-g1cftve.evolven.corp

Then I created a keytab file for the evolvendbclientuser on the active directory server. Note that I set the crypto parameter to ALL, you can set a specific encryption algorithm (AES-128, AES-256) if desired. Just make sure that your kdc server supports that encryption type and it's allowed in the krb5.conf file):
ktpass -princ evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP -mapuser EVOLVEN\evolvendbclientuser -crypto ALL -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -pass <password> -out evolvendbclientuser.keytab -SetPass

Next, I uploaded the keytab file to the RHEL server into the /etc directory. Then Updated my Jaas file to reference the new keytab file and principal to my evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP.
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="/etc/evolvendbclientuser.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    principal="evolvendbclientuser@EVOLVEN.CORP"
    doNotPrompt=true
    debug=true;
};

For reference my krb5.conf file:
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
    rnds = false
    default_realm = EVOLVEN.CORP
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    ticket_lifetime = 30d
    renew_lifetime = 30d
    forwardable = true
    udp_preference_limit = 0
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
    permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac

[realms]
    EVOLVEN.CORP = {
        kdc = EC2AMAZ-AEHRC46.evolven.corp
        admin_server = EC2AMAZ-AEHRC46.evolven.corp
    }

Finally, I was sick and tired of launching my Tomcat app and waiting it to fail so I wrote a little Java app that you can compile alongside your JDBC adapter to test the connections:
You'll want to put this into the same directory as your mssql-jdbc jar.
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCConnectionWrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Check if a connection string is provided as an argument
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please provide the JDBC connection string as an argument.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Capture the JDBC connection string from the command-line argument
        String jdbcUrl = args[0];

        System.out.println("Connecting to: " + jdbcUrl);

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

You can then compile and test the JDBC connectivity. Note the additional parameters that tell the JDBC adapter to use the krb5.conf file and the JaaS configuration for use by the JDBC adapter. Also bumped up the logging.
java -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false \
     -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/tomcat/bin/jaas.conf \
     -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf \
     -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true \
     -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true \
     -cp .:mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar JDBCConnectionWrapper \
     "jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQL-G1CFTVE.evolven.corp:1433;DatabaseName=master;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true"

Now instead of getting the dreaded "Integrated authentication failed" and  Defective token detected (Mechanism level: AP_REP token id does not match!) error. I get:
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_IN_PROCESS
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
Krb5Context setting peerSeqNumber to: 813842378
Connected to the database!

Thank you all so much! If you are struggling with this, I hope this helps!
